# Regex: Exclude a substring in fn:matches

Tags: regex, xml, xquery

I have an config xml as

```
    <cfg:property name="Gallery.*.*">GalleryPort</cfg:property>
    <cfg:property name="Office.*.*">OfficePort</cfg:property>
    <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Closet$">LivingCloset</cfg:property>
    <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Lights$">LivingLights</cfg:property>
```

I use xquery to get the value for the property using

> $dynamicURN := $config//cfg:property[matches($key, @name)]/text()

$key is received from database and the urn is the fetched.
What should be the fourth property name so that it can catch any string other than Closet or Lights after Home.Living.?

Example: I tried

`<cfg:property name=" Home.Living.[A-Z-[LIGHTS]]">LivingMisc</cfg:property>`

`<cfg:property name=" Home.Living.[^'(LIGHTS)']">LivingMisc</cfg:property>`

Possible values for key are:

```
Home.Living.Lights
Home.Living.Light
Home.Living.Closed
Home.Living.Closet
Home.Living.Table
```

The respective output should be

```
LivingLights
LivingMisc
LivingMisc
LivingCloset
LivingMisc
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal, but complete and verifiable sample of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For XQuery questions, this means a minimal, but complete input XML sample, all of the XQuery code and the output you expect.

Comment: You did not make it any clearer I'm afraid. You did not add the things I have asked about.

Comment: It would be nice to have some Examples of what $key can come in says. Just to make sure I understand. $key comes in and you  Match @name to the key and get the text of the property element. You want to add another property that will get match any other key that has Home.Living. other then Home.Living.Closet and Home.Living.Lights. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get you what you need, but you could do it another way that is more performent at scale. Just so you know that regex will be evaluated for each item it finds. So for every node it finds its going to be 3 expressions.

```
declare namespace cfg = "somthinghere";

let $key := ("Home.Living.Lights","Home.Living.Closet","Home.Living.anyOtherString","Home.Living.anotherString")[1]

let $config :=
<config>
  <cfg:property name="Gallery.*.*">GalleryPort</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Office.*.*">OfficePort</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Closet$">LivingCloset</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Lights$">LivingLights</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Home.Living.[^Closet|Lights]">LivingMisc</cfg:property>
</config>
let $option := $config//cfg:property[fn:matches($key, @name )]/text()
return $option
```

**Update:**

Since you can't use negative lookahead in xquery you could try something like this. Don't use Name for the other home.living. matches. So the code here will first look at @name. If it finds something it will stop. If it doesn't find something then it will look at @fallback and match off of that.

It just means the keys that aren't found in the first match will be running a 2nd match so its just more expressions for those items.

```
declare namespace cfg = "somthinghere";

let $key := (
  "Home.Living.Lights",
  "Home.Living.Closet",
  "Home.Living.anyOtherString",
  "Home.Living.anotherString",
  "Home.Living.Close",
  "Gallery"
)[2]

let $config :=
<config>
  <cfg:property name="Gallery.*.*">GalleryPort</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Office.*.*">OfficePort</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Closet$">LivingCloset</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property name="Home.Living.Lights$">LivingLights</cfg:property>
  <cfg:property fallback="Home.Living.*">LivingMisc</cfg:property>
</config>
return ($config//cfg:property[fn:matches($key, @name )]/text()[1], $config//cfg:property[fn:matches($key, @fallback )]/text()[1])[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler for taking the time to answer and fr the suggestions. I just have limited room to change the existing code. You can take a look at the updated question.

Comment: So i changed my answer to fit your updated question. I'm still not 100% sure what the end goal is of you question but i did say what i think it is in a comment on your question and this answer is based on that.

Comment: [^Closet|Lights] excludes all the characters in those two words, like Close, Light etc. I want to exclude those two words as a whole. Substrings should get along ok.

Comment: So what you are wanting is negative lookahead and it's not supported in xquery. Does it have to find the property by using match and only the name attribute? Because you could solve this another way.

Comment: The code already exists and I dont want to touch that so only matches would do. But you could suggest something. And thanks for being patient.

Comment: I've added an example of another way to do it. It is really splitting the regex into two statements since you can't use any lookaheads or look behideds in xquery you really need to have two different statements.